# Is there a universal USB API for smartphones?

Tags: usb, smartphone

Just what the title states - Is there such a thing as a USB framework for smartphones s.a Android, BB, WP?

Answer (score 0):

No there is not.  Most platforms will expose part of the device as removable storage so you can transfer files but everything else is custom